# $PATH extended at .bashrc not available within git hook script

Tags: git, bash

I need to run a certain command when a push is received in a repository. That binary is located at a custom path which I added to .bashrc and works normally from the shell. I wrote a little script as a git hook. However, the .bashrc additions don't seem to affect this script.

I've tried putting `bash ~/.bashrc` at the top of the script but didn't work. If I run the script manually, say `$ sh post-receive`, it works just fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is probably run as a different user, or is being invoked with options to disable interactive features and/or startup scripts. That's as it should be; nothing is "wrong" here really.

You can add `. /home/you/.bashrc` as a quick and dirty workaround; or, more properly, just amend the script's PATH directly; or, even more properly, modularize dependencies e.g. by putting the code in a separate file which you source both from your `.bashrc` and from this script - but for this isolated case, that´s certainly overkill.

The command to "include" a file of shell scipt is called "source" or "dot"; in Bash, `source` is available as a synonym, but in proper Bourne shell, it's a literal dot (aka period, full stop):

```
. /path/to/stuff
```

Comment: This has been very useful for fixing Jekyll dependencies encountered as part of a git `post-update` hook. Sourcing `. ~/.bash_profile` is probably a dirty method but considering how most will install rvm and subsequent gems it's easily a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 8):

Check your .bashrc
In some distrib, the end of the script is skipped when not exec in interactive mode.
Just bring the usefull stuff you need over the skip part.

It looks to that:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
  *i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ❤️ it was the issue in my case

Answer (score 2):

That `bash ~/.bashrc` spawns a new shell which executes the file called `.bashrc`, and any state that is within this subshell is naturally lost when that subshell exits -- which it has to do before moving on to the second line of your *actual* script that contains the call.