# Why is my Ruby Git script hook run with the wrong $PATH?

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, environment-variables

I'm using RVM. I wrote a Git `pre-commit` hook for a project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts RUBY_VERSION
puts `echo $PATH`
exit(1)
```

which outputs this when run by Git:

```
$ git ci -m 'foo'
1.8.7
/usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/mgoerlich/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/mgoerlich/.dotfiles/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/Users/mgoerlich/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

It seems to run with the wrong version of Ruby because `$PATH` is not the same as in bash or zsh or sh. It seems like git is manipulating `$PATH`. When run manually, I get this:

```
$ .git/hooks/pre-commit
2.0.0
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/bin:/Users/mgoerlich/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/mgoerlich/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/mgoerlich/.dotfiles/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/Users/mgoerlich/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

In the output of the commit hook, there are two paths prepended, one of them `/usr/bin` where the system Ruby's executable is placed.

Is this a known behavior? Can I manipulate that somehow? I know I could specify the full path to the correct Ruby version in the shebang, but this is not what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$PATH extended at .bashrc not available within git hook script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405693/path-extended-at-bashrc-not-available-within-git-hook-script)

Comment: same for Python's virtualenv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037284/how-can-i-run-a-virtualenv-python-script-as-a-git-pre-commit-hook

Comment: same for rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/374

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason i didn't wanted to use `env` instead of a fixed path to ruby or a rvm wrapper was that this is for a Team Project and not everyone in the Team is using RVM.

My final solution was to write my own wrapper script an add it to that project.

All client-side git hooks 're living in `$PROJECT/bin/hooks`, all of them ruby scripts.
Now, i've just put that mentioned wrapper in there, and created a symlink to that wrapper in `$PROJECT/.git/hooks` for all the hooks.

The script check's if RVM is used and if so fixes the `$PATH` var and if there are `.ruby-version` and/or `.ruby-gemset` files in the project root it loads the according version/gemset.

Then it'll run the according ruby script 
Here's the wrapper in case you're interested:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$HOME/.rvm/bin" ]; then
  PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

  if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
    rvm use "$(cat .ruby-version)"
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
    rvm gemset use "$(cat .ruby-gemset)"
  fi
fi
ruby "bin/hooks/$(basename "$0").rb"
```

So, i'll get my rvm version/gemset and everybody else the ruby version they have in their PATH, and everyone is Happy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set ruby to a wrapper:

```
#!$rvm_path/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p195/ruby
```

You can simplify it with an alias:

```
rvm alias create git_hooks 2.0.0-p195
```

And then the ne shebang will look like this:

```
#!$rvm_path/wrappers/git_hooks/ruby
```

In the file just make sure to replace `$rvm_path` with `/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm` so finally it looks like:

```
#!/Users/mgoerlich/.rvm/wrappers/git_hooks/ruby
```

Comment: So, there is no way i can use `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: there is rvm-shell but it still will not be in PATH in the hook

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is: the `.git` file structure:

- `.git/hooks/pre-commit`
- `.git/hooks/pre-commit-main.rb`

.git/hooks/pre-commit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH="$THE_GOOD_PATH"
ruby "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit-main.rb"
```

.git/hooks/pre-commit-main.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Then, when you call `git commit`, make sure that `THE_GOOD_PATH`, is defined:

```
export THE_GOOD_PATH="$PATH"
git commit
```

You could also export `THE_GOOD_PATH="$PATH"` from your `.profile` or the toplevel of your application and symlink all hooks to a single file.

This method has the advantage of being rbenv agnostic: it also works with RVM or Python virtualenv.

I wrote to the Git developers at: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/258454 asking them to leave our `PATH` alone, but the initial reply was WONTFIX.