# pre-commit hook doesn't check if saved changes are staged before running

Tags: git, bash, githooks, pre-commit

I followed [this guide on creating git pre-commit hooks](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/), and so far I really like the benefit it's given me.

However, I have a problem when I use it:

1. I write some code, perhaps something that doesn't pass a rubocop inspection.
2. I stage it, then attempt to commit it. The pre-commit hook works as intended.
3. I go and fix the issues that rubocop reported.
4. I save the changes, *but forget to `add` it to the index*.

When I commit, my script just takes the list of files changed that are  in `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM`, runs rubocop on each of them, and quits if there's any issues.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set the ruby environment from local/rvm, depending on your machine.
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515769
if [ -d "$HOME/.rvm/bin" ]; then
  PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

  if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
    rvm use "$(cat .ruby-version)"
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
    rvm gemset use "$(cat .ruby-gemset)"
  fi
fi

# http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/
FILES_PATTERN='\.rb(\..+)?$'
FORBIDDEN='debug'

# Quit if no ruby files are being checked in.
RB_FILES=$(git df --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep -Ec $FILES_PATTERN)
if [ "$RB_FILES" = "0" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | \
    grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | \
    GREP_COLOR='37;41' xargs grep --color --with-filename -n $FORBIDDEN && \
    echo 'Please remove debugging statements before commiting.' && exit 1

# Pull in altered files, check with rubocop.
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | \
    grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | xargs rubocop -f simple | \
    grep 'no offences detected' && exit 0
# If it didn't exit 0 above, warn of issues, output results.
echo 'Rubocop has detected issues with your commit.' && \
    git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | \
    grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | xargs rubocop -f simple && exit 1
```

I don't want to use `sed` to parse through the results of `git diff`. Is there an easier way to ensure that I'm checking the *index*, opposed to the file as it appears on disk?

My instinct tells me that there may be a way to check if there are any files that are both in `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=M` *and* `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M`, and just quit if that's the case.

Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hi if you still have the piece of code I would be glad if you would update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to have files as they are in index at hand.

To do so, you can do `git stash -k` (keeping index) before running your utility and `git stash pop` afterwards assuming it won't change anything so that no conflicts would appear.

Comment: It's a start. It doesn't evaluate anything that isn't on staging (which is good), but it does seem to throw away any changes that I forgot to stage, requiring me to rewrite them.

Comment: `git stash pop` should bring back all changes made in working tree but not added to commit. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah I think I may have missed an `exit [0|1]` when running `git stash pop` or something, because it's much better now. My bash is terrible, thanks.