# Guard-jasmine syntax errors only when run from git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, jasmine, guard, pre-commit-hook

I have a pre-commit hook with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd web
bundle exec guard-jasmine
```

(it cds into web because the Gemfile and app are set there)

When committing, I get a number of syntax errors, the first of which is this:

```
/Users/myusrname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:400:in `require':
/Users/myusrname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/guard-jasmine-1.16.0/lib/guard/jasmine.rb:25: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
server:                   :auto,

/Users/myusrname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/guard-jasmine-1.16.0/lib/guard/jasmine.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
server:                   :auto,
```

`bundle exec guard-jasmine` and `guard-jasmine` run fine when typed into the command line

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like guard-jasmine is running with Ruby 1.8.7, even if the RVM gem path contains ruby-2.0.0-p0. When using the new Ruby 1.9 Hash syntax in Ruby 1.8, the error `odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)` is thrown.

You need to either

- Make sure the Git pre-commit-hook is using at least Ruby 1.9
- Use Guard::Jasmine version 1.14.0, which runs fine on Ruby 1.8

Since Ruby 1.8.7 is end-of-life anyway, I'd suggest to try to initialize RVM in the pre-commit-hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd web
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm reload > /dev/null
bundle exec guard-jasmine
```

This implies you've set a default Ruby version

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Comment: I think it is using ruby 1.8.7, I'll need to do some digging to see how I can change it, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515769/why-is-my-ruby-git-script-hook-run-with-the-wrong-path <-- this was also helpful

Answer (score 0):

## best solution so far (at least for me):

```
rvm reload || exit $?
RUBY=`which ruby`
RUBY_DIR=`dirname $RUBY`
GEM_DIR=`rvm gemdir`
export PATH="$GEM_DIR/bin:$RUBY_DIR:$PATH"

gem install bundler
bundle install

bundle exec guard-jasmine
```

Comment: I ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/debugwand/6378438 - No installation of bundler or bundle install.